# Removing a character from array

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been trying to get my head around this for a while now;

The program I have written should ask a user to input a sentence of which every letter would be stored within each sell of the array. Here's what the menu looks like:

```
void displayMenu() {
    cout << "\n\n\n           ________MENU________\n";
    cout << "\n STOP                                    0";
    cout << "\n Input text                              1";
    cout << "\n Output text                             2";
    cout << "\n Length of text                          3";
    cout << "\n Put text in uppercase                   4 - (Works)";
    cout << "\n Count duplicates of given letter        5 - (Works)";
    cout << "\n Remove all occurrences of given letter  6 - Sort of Works?";
}
```

As you can see, option 6 asks the user to input a character and it should then remove all occurrences of that letter within the array.

Full code: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/33c380881f145e9383fc

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction in terms of completing this task? Is there something I'm missing? I just cannot get my head around it.

So say for example the array was `H, e, l, l, o` and I wanted to remove `l` then the output should be `H, e, o`.

I've done option 5 and I believe option 6 should be similar to it?

I kind of gathered that I have to probably make some sort of 'for loop' or 'while loop' but I'm not sure on how to actually remove the value from the array.

EDIT:
Here's what I made so far however it doesn't work:

```
void removeAllOccurrences(char text[], char letter)
{
    int index(0);
    while (text[index] != EOT)
    {
        if ((text[index] == letter) || (text[index] == toupper(letter)))
        {
            text[index] = text[index + 1];
        }
        ++index;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a trivial task. So, take some time and effort to prepare a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) if you want to get help from experienced programmer on StackOverflow. They will unlikely read any code snippet that doesn't fit to the screen.

Comment: @Drop I've had a go at creating one function myself but it just does nothing :( - Please see edit ^^

Comment: Are you restricted to built-in arrays, or solution with standard containers (which you should always prefer) will do the trick?

Comment: @Drop Afraid I'm stuck with built-in arrays however, if there is an alternative way of doing it, I will be more than happy to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using a `std::string`.

If you insist on using an array, at-least use a `std::array`, then you can 'remove' elements like this:

```
std::array<char, 5> text {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
std::fill(std::remove(std::begin(text), std::end(text), 'l'), std::end(text), '\0');
```

Note this does not change the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the easiest way to accomplish this would be to iterate over the char array, and add each char to a new char array except for the one the user input.

This will leave you with a fresh char array without the selected char.